# Making an Enum Map from the Enum Constructor for a static map

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

Okay, so now I have my enumMap,but it doesn't work anyway. Like, when I try to do this:

```
            Status inStatus = Enum.valueOf(Status, ENUM_MAP.get(02));
```

It inStatus ends up being null :\

y tho.

I'm working in Java, and basically, for now I have this:

```
private static final HashMap<Integer,Status> ENUM_MAP = 
                    new HashMap<Integer,Status>();
...
ENUM_MAP.put(0, Status.A);
ENUM_MAP.put(1, Status.B);
ENUM_MAP.put(2, Status.C);
```

And it works. But I want my `enum` to do it internally sort of like this, but it doesn't work.

```
public static enum Status{
    A(0),B(1),C(2);
    protected static final HashMap<Integer,Status> ENUM_MAP =
                    new HashMap<Integer,Status>();
    private final Integer state;
    private Status(Integer state){
        this.state = state;
        ENUM_MAP.put(this.state, **this**);
    }
}
```

the **this** is what I'm trying to figure out, so that I don't have to write it, and it gets built by the enum nice and easy. Note, I don't want state to be public, and I don't know how else to go from the ordinal integer to the String version of the name. (if there's even a way, that would simplify this.)

EDIT:

This seemed to work best, only 2 extra lines (though my compiler is telling me it is leaky)
And it keeps my map as private as I wanted it.

```
    private static final Map<Integer,Status> ENUM_MAP=new HashMap<>();

    public static enum Status{
        A(0),B(1),C(2);
        private final Integer state;
        private Status(Integer state){
            this.state=state;
            ENUM_MAP.put(this.state, this);
        }//end private Status(int state)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a built-in conversion from the integer *ordinal* to its corresponding enum value?

Comment: What's not "nice and easy" about having to write `this`?

Comment: There are obnoxious scoping rules involved. tl;dr you can do this but you need to put the map initialization into a `static` block (and use `EnumMap`, and wrap it in `unmodifiableMap` before assigning it to the constant).

Comment: @ernest_k In this case, going from the ordinal would be okay, but I was also trying to go from the assigned values (i.e. suppose 0,1,2 was 4, 18,47, instead) I kinda wanted to know how to do both options though, for reference. 
@Sweeper, it doesn't actually let you put ```this``` there. I want where that is to be Status.A, Status.B, and Status.C respectively.
@chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I looked at some questions that did that, but they had the enum as the key, but I want Integer to be the key, EnumMap doesn't like that, from my understanding.

Comment: @Sweeper Actually it did let me use this, but not the way it was before for reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner class to hold static map:

```
public static class Holder {
    static Map<Integer, Status> statusMap = new HashMap<>();
}
private Status(Integer state){
    this.state = state;
    Holder.statusMap.put(state, this);
}
public static Status byState(Integer state) {
    return Holder.statusMap.get(state;
}
```

*I don't want state to be public* - if state is the key to your map, you will probably send state, so I don't understand your comment

Comment: Then when I try to use it outside of the class is says it can't find package Holder. :\

Comment: @procersapientiae added `byState` method

Comment: I was trying to keep it all private, your answer helped me synthesize a solution, if you check my question I edited it based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the map on demand when the values are being searched. You can't add the value to the map in the constructor.

Here's what you could do (you have to make a lookup method available anyway):

```
public static enum Status {
    A(0), B(1), C(2);

    protected static final HashMap<Integer, Status> ENUM_MAP = 
            new HashMap<Integer, Status>();
    private final Integer state;

    private Status(Integer state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    //finds a mapped value or maps one for the key
    public static Status find(int i) {
        if (ENUM_MAP.containsKey(i)) {
            return ENUM_MAP.get(i);
        }

        Status found = null;
        for (Status s : values()) {
            if (i == s.state) {
                found = s;
                ENUM_MAP.put(i, s);
                break;
            }
        }

        return found;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid having anything be public in the class, though this is an interesting option. Some of the other answers lead me to what I needed.

Comment: @procersapientiae so where do you need to resolve the mapping? from inside the enum class itself?

Comment: yeah, I was hoping the only thing showing would be the protected ENUM thing, but I'm happy with what I decided on, the other option to use a static block would have worked for keeping it internal, but having it belong to it's owner class worked better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static block:

```
public enum Status{
    A(0),B(1),C(2);
    protected static final HashMap<Integer,Status> ENUM_MAP =
                    new HashMap<Integer,Status>();

    static {
      for(Status status : Status.values()) {
        ENUM_MAP.put(status.state, status);
      }
    }
    private final Integer state;
    private Status(Integer state){
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's starting to make sense to me. Is that because the code at the start of the class executes, so it makes an instances of itself using the  private constructor, and then does what's in the random static block next? That would probably make it so I never needed to make the states if I wanted to use ordinal().

Comment: Another question, if it's done in the constructor vs static block, does it happen at compile-time, or execution?

Comment: They happen at runtime. `static` keyword means this part of the code belongs to the class itself, not the instances of it. Enum is actually specific type of class. All of its fields can be written as `public static final A = new Status(1); ...`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was starting to pick up on that after getting confused why I could use and enum like a generic extended Enum (capital), and now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This (albeit long) one-line definition of ENUM_MAP is final and immutable, and will contain all the Status values if you add more. It is safe to share as a public member - no subsequent changes are permitted because the declaration uses `Map.copyOf()`:

```
public enum Status{
    A(0),B(1),C(2);
    private final Integer state;
    private Status(Integer state){
        this.state=state;
    }
    public static final Map<Integer,Status> ENUM_MAP = 
        Map.copyOf(Arrays.stream(values())
                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(st -> st.state, st -> st)));
```

The value of ENUM_MAP is initialised with all the enum values by key state to value of the enumeration.

This example program shows how to lookup enum values by state or name - including `Status.valueOf(String)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("ENUM_MAP="+Status.ENUM_MAP);
    System.out.println("ENUM_MAP.get(1)="+Status.ENUM_MAP.get(1));
    System.out.println("ENUM_MAP.get(5)="+Status.ENUM_MAP.get(5));

    System.out.println("Status.valueOf(\"A\")="+Status.valueOf("A"));
    System.out.println("Enum.valueOf(Status.class, \"A\")="+Enum.valueOf(Status.class, "A"));

    // Next line fails (as expected) as ENUM_MAP cannot be changed
    Status.ENUM_MAP.put(10, Status.C);
}
```

This prints:

```
ENUM_MAP={0=A, 1=B, 2=C}
ENUM_MAP.get(1)=B
ENUM_MAP.get(5)=null
Status.valueOf("A")=A
Enum.valueOf(Status.class, "A")=A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

The call `Status.valueOf("A")` does same as `Enum.valueOf(Status.class, "A")`.

Comment: I'm defintely going to have to read a bit about what exactly that's doing.